# Cast causes "Operation could destabilize the runtime" on one ASP.NET 4.0 box and not another

Tags: .net-4.0, clr

Here's (part of) a simple deserialization method that I've used in .NET 2.0 for years.  `T` is an unconstrained type parameter.

```
protected virtual T ItemFromString(string s) {

    if (typeof(T).IsPrimitive ||
        typeof(T) == typeof(string)) {

        try {
            // needed for string, too: compiler doesn't allow (T)s
            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(s, typeof(T));
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            // stuff
        }
    }
}
```

I changed the application pool to run in 4.0, and everything was fine — until I deployed it to the remote server.  There, I get "Operation could destabilize the runtime" on the line

```
return (T)Convert.ChangeType(s, typeof(T));
```

(Actually the line reported is the ending brace of the method, but I've narrowed it down to that line.)

The problem goes away if I change the runtime back to 2.0.

The runtime versions are both `4.0.30319`.  The app is otherwise identical, including `web.config`.  Both apps using shared application pools and running in Full trust.  Presumably another setting is affecting it, but I have no idea how to figure out what.

Everything I've found about this involves `Reflection.Emit` or covariance, which I'm not using.

Any leads?

Thanks.

Comment: I think the proper google query for this is +allowpartiallytrustedcallers +verificationexception

Comment: @Hans, thanks for the reply.  I came across that as well and forgot to mention that the remote application is running in Full trust.  Shouldn't that overcome the `AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers` issue?  Besides, does the call I'm making really require it?

Comment: Always worth triple-checking this when the exception says otherwise.

Comment: Is your machine running a 64 bit CLR? I assume the server runs on x64, but maybe your machine runs x86... That would at least explain the different behaviour

Comment: @dema80, thanks for the comment.  Both machines are 64-bit, and the assembly in question targets the default platform (AnyCPU).  But my local process is 32-bit, because the app uses Access and there's no 64-bit driver for JET — I have to set "Enable 32-bit apps" to `true`.  My remote control panel doesn't let me set this, but the Access db works, so I assume it is set, and therefore that both apps run in a 32-bit process.

Comment: To be extra sure, try to target x86 and see if something changes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that this question has been viewed `0x80` times, I'll post the solution I recently used when I could no longer put off the move to .NET 4.

You have to target the .NET 4 platform in the build, and set the following assembly property.

```
using System.Security;

// Needed to enable generic deserialization in partial trust.
[assembly: SecurityRules(SecurityRuleSet.Level1)]
```

I'd commented that I was in full trust mode, but I must have been wrong about that.  This is *only* an issue in partially-trusted environments.